# android native ndk jnienv* env

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, native

I am new in android Native App development. For some reseons I need to run an .so file at the sdcard from an ELF file(executable file). I need to define JNIEnv* env variable in ELF file and pass that to .so file with dlopen command, OR define JNIEnv* env in .so file, I want to send an sms in my Native Android Application.
My native method is like below:

```
void Java_com_example_calljavaservice_MainActivity_getJniString() {
    //I should define env variable here
    jclass smsManagerClz = (*env)->FindClass(env,
                    "android/telephony/SmsManager");

    jmethodID getDefaultMethodID = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, smsManagerClz,"getDefault", "()Landroid/telephony/SmsManager;");
    jobject smsManagerObj = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, smsManagerClz, getDefaultMethodID);
    jmethodID sendSMSMethodID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, smsManagerClz, "sendTextMessage","(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;""Landroid/app/PendingIntent;Landroid/app/PendingIntent;)V");

    jstring number = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "5554");

    jstring text = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "sms content");


     jstring nullString = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "");

     (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, smsManagerObj, sendSMSMethodID, number, nullString, text, NULL, NULL);
}
```

I don't have JNIEnv* env in my method parameters, and I want to define env variable in my method, but I don't know how define that.I don't want to send env variable to my method.
suppose I want to call my .so file from an ELF file in the sdcard, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you give your function a name like `Java_com_example_calljavaservice_MainActivity_getJniString` unless it's going to be called from Java? (and if it's called from Java, it will receive a `JNIEnv*`)

Comment: yes, if its called from java, it will receive a JNIEnv*, but i dont want call that from java, i need execute this file(an executable file) from command line of from another c method in another file.